# PHP Variables passing in webpage

Tags: php, session, variables

In my php file I am creating a login, into extreme detail so Im not gonna post it but I am also new to php and I need help with one thing. I'm not sure if `$_SESSION` could work for this but if it does I wouldn't know how to do it.

1. This is what i'm wondering...
   If i had someone log in could I have a variable (there username so I don't care if it is stored in the url somehow.) be passed from page to page and be read into each file by calling it.  Then could I also have the variable be emptied
2. Also one simpler problem...how could I create a folder in php?

My directory still isn't working

```
if (is_writable('/users')) {
  if (mkdir('/users/$finalusername')) {
    // success
  }
}
$myFile = "/users/$finalusername/$finalusername.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("There was an error in creating your account.  <br />");
$stringData = "$finalusername\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "$finalpass\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "$finalemail\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: I actually did solve it but it won't work when I have it online. I had  each page read a variable from a text file and the variable was set when someone logged in and destroyed when someone logged out but this wouldn't work if I had more than one person logged in at a time. And to be honest I dont know how to use $SESSION

Comment: If you tried something, then post some code and explain exactly why it didn't work.  Stack Overflow is not a site for vomiting code up for you on command.  You have to put forth some effort.

Comment: I have tried $SESSION start for your information I did not succeed and this is a website for getting help...as I am doing why are you commenting...and I did try passing variable soooo

Comment: Put some actual code in your question.

Comment: I don't have and relevant code because im at a complete fail on this on this

Comment: Well, I could code this up for you.  I charge $30/hour, rounded up to the nearest hour and with the first hour paid up front. Do you have Paypal?

Comment: I just turned 16, Im trying to set a future in this so Im learning it now. No thankyou.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a site to give you code for free.  [Rent a Coder](http://www.rent-acoder.com/) would probably better suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Do NOT* pass an authentication value of any sort in the URL query string. It would be trivial for users to tamper with their settings (or other users' settings) if passed that way.

`$_SESSION` is more ideal for this kind of thing, and simple to implement.  Upon successful login, set a session variable for the user:

```
// Must be called to initiate session
session_start();

// Login was successful 
$_SESSION['username'] = $the_username;

// On other pages:
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  // user is logged in
}
else // show the login form
```

To log a user out:

```
// Method 1 only unsets the username to log out the user
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);

// Alternatively you can destroy the whole session, if
// you are not using it for anything else the user may need again
// despite not being logged in (maybe his preferred language, for example)
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION);
```

To create a directory with PHP, use `mkdir()`.  The web server user account must have write access to the directory in which the new directory is created for it to work.

```
if (is_writable('/path/to/parentdir')) {
  if (mkdir('/path/to/parentdir/new_directory')) {
    // success
  }
  else {
    // handle error
  }
}
else // This directory has to be writable by the web server!
```

Comment: So to log out? session_end(); $_SESSION['username'] = $the_username;

Comment: To Logout: `session_start(); session_destroy(); unset($_SESSION);` You must start the session on the logout page before you can destroy it.

Comment: @SpencerMay See addition above - two methods to log out.

Comment: @SpencerMay lol, I don't really need the upvotes. Please mark the answer as accepted if you're satisfied though, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a link for each question

[Simple Login Form in PHP with Sessions](http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html)

Please dont make your username appear in the address using get variables. Try $_SESSION and $_POST combined to get a good result.

Imagine if i change my adress from `www.yourpage.com?username=kypros` to `www.yourpage.com?username=administrator`, will that make me an administrator immediately?

As for the second question what you want is the 
[mkdir() function to create new folders](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: Thankyou :) and good point on the url... I also dont know why but the mkdir() wasn't working for me earlier.

Comment: If it's not working as you'd expect my guess would be a problem with your write privileges on the server or a misspell of some kind since its a pretty straight forward command

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is the best answer for you. It works by storing a cookie on the client (sent as part of the HTTP response) with a unique session id. This is then sent back with each request sent from the client to your server, until the cookie is unset. The server then stores associated information in a temporary session variable. Destroying the session on the server side (by timeout or via your code) would also mean the user would be logged out (no information is stored for the session).

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir()` is a function used to create a directory.

Ideally you would use a database to store user login details. Then use a form where someone can input their username and password. When they hit the submit button the form would post the values the person inputted to the login script. The login script would then search the database to see if the username and password match any of the ones in the dababase. If they do then you can use `session_start()` to create a session and can create a `$_SESSION` variable equal to the username the user entered.

Use the `session_start()` function on all the webpages that you want to have content displayed depending on if the person is logged in or not.

You could use an `if()` loop to find out if the `$_SESSION['username']` exists and display content if it does. 
To end a session use the `session_destory()` function.